# I can not put action with payload in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I put action with payload in redux-saga,the action is work,but it can not get payload

action:

```
export const takeKey = createAction("TAKE_KEY_REQUEST", data => {
  //when it come from redux-saga,it does't console
  console.log("data",data) 
  return data;
});
```

redux-saga

```
//in this function,I put action
function* loginAsync(action) {
  yield put({type:"TAKE_KEY_REQUEST",payload:{test:"test"}})
}

//this get type:"TAKE_KEY_REQUEST"
function* takeKeyAsync(action) {
  //console
  //from page:action,{type:"TAKE_KEY_REQUEST",payload:{}}
  //from saga:action,{type: "TAKE_KEY_REQUEST", @@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION: true}
  console.log("action",action)
}
```

Comment: in this case the `put` in the saga is definitely putting your action back into the middleware. but the "action creator" is not part of the middleware and isn't listening for that type and will never run. you could convert that "action creator" into a saga of its own that `take`s "TAKE_KEY_REQUEST"

Comment: It looks like your `loginAsync` saga is trying to `put()` an action that is of the same type as those created by the `takeKey()` creator. If you want `loginAsync` to put those kind of actions, import and use the actionCreator in the saga: `yield put(takeKey({test: 'test'}))`. If, instead, you want one of your two sagas to respond to the takeKey and to operate on the data in its payload, can you add to your examples with more detail? Perhaps describe more of the problem, or show more of your saga configuration.

Comment: @李馥亦 Any updates on this?